# Python regex to extract positive and negative numbers between two special characters

Tags: python, regex

Need to extract value from a string, the value can contain a comma, a decimal point, both comma and decimal point, without any of comma or decimal point, with any of comma or decimal.

For example:

```
1,921.15
921.15
921
1,921

re.findall(r'[-+]?\d+[,.]?\d*',st)[3]" its extracting only 1,921 but not as 1,921.15


st='["FL gr_20 PT10 MT3\'><strong>1,921.15</strong>"]'
```

I have tried `re.findall(r'[-+]?\d+[,.]?\d*',st)[3]` its extracting only 1,921 but not as 1,921.15

From below string st, using re module, I need to extract the value 1,921.15

```
st='["FL gr_20 PT10 MT3\'><strong>1,921.15</strong>"]'

Expected = 1,921.15
Actual = 1,921
```

Comment: `re.findall(r"\d+,{0,1}\d+\.{0,1}\d+", "FL gr_20 PT10 MT3\'><strong>1,921.15</strong>")`? Ok with the edit you have `<strong>` tags. I would suggest not to use regex for html data.

Comment: In your example `["FL gr_20 PT10 MT3\'>1,921.15"]` why did it not find 4 matches? `'20'`, `'10'`, `'3'`, and `'1,921.15'`

Comment: @Buckeye14Guy: Thanks its working as expected.  Also could you please tell me what does ",{0,1}" mean here in r"\d+,{0,1}\d+\.{0,1}\d+"

Comment: {0,1} is used to match 0 or 1 occurrences, it's like what "?" does.

Comment: @prashantbj Try `re.findall(r'[-+]?(?<!\d)\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*(?:\.\d+)?(?!\d)', text)`

Comment: Which solution you are using? Should I post my solution as an answer? Is it helpful?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew : I am using Buckeye14Guy solution, as "re.findall(r'[-+]?(?<!\d)\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*(?:\.\d+)?(?!\d)', text)"  is not getting the values if it doesn't has comma.   Ex:>>> st='["FL gr_20 PT10 MT3\'><strong>1921.15</strong>"]'
>>> re.findall(r'[-+]?(?<!\d)\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*(?:\.\d+)?(?!\d)', st)
['20', '10', '3', '15']

Comment: @prashantbj Do you realize it only matches numbers with at least 3 digits? Is it your intention? If not, try `re.findall(r'[-+]?(?<!\d)(?:\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*|\d+)(?:\.\d+)?(?!\d)', text)`

Comment: Just found a regex to extract numbers like `(?<!\w)[-+]?\d{1,3}(?:(?:,\d{3})*|\d*)(?:\.\d+)?(?:[eE][-+]?\d+|[x×*]10(?:\^[-+]?\d+|[⁻⁺]?[⁰¹²³⁴-⁹]+))?(?!\w)`, it might be a better bet for a general case.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Thanks for the updated solution, unable to extract value, if value has 2 or more commas, just looking for a solution which can find value from all the below example strings ......
st='["FL gr_20 T3\'><strong>1,921.15</strong>"]'  
st='["FL gr_20 T3\'><strong>921.15</strong>"]'  
st='["FL gr_20 T3\'><strong>21.15</strong>"]'  
st='["FL gr_20 T3\'><strong>1,11,921.15</strong>"]'  
st='["FL gr_20 T3\'><strong>1,921</strong>"]'  
st='["FL gr_20 T3\'><strong>112921</strong>"]'  
st='["FL gr_20 T3\'><strong>1.15</strong>"]'  
st='["FL gr_20 T3\'><strong>1</strong>"]'

Comment: What about `re.findall(r'>(\d[\d,.]*)<', text)`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Thanks its working as expected for all the values. Also could you please tell me the regex r'>(\d[\d,.]*)<' how it works.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Also how about values if it has '-ve' sign ex: -1,11,022.99', need to extract such values along with '-ve' sign, ie '-1,11,022.99'. Could you please try this.

Comment: I posted an answer, please check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In general**, when you want to extract positive or negative integer or float numbers from text using Python regex, you can use the following pattern

```
re.findall(r'[-+]?(?:\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})+|\d+)(?:\.\d+)?', text)
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/IxrVBG/2). **Note**: `\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})+` alternative matches integer numbers with comma as a thousand separator. You may adjust it to match the thousand separator you need, say, `\xA0` if the thousand separator is a non-breaking space, or `\.` if it is a dot, etc.

Some more options will look like

```
re.findall(r'[-+]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?', text) # Integer part is compulsory, e.g. 5.55
re.findall(r'[-+]?\d*\.?\d+', text)     # Also matches .57 or -.76
```

**Here**, you want to extract any number in between `>` and `<` chars.

You may use

```
re.findall(r'>([-+]?\d[\d,.]*)<', text)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/2gX8g3/2).

**Details**

- `>` - a `>` char
- `([-+]?\d[\d,.]*)` - Group 1:

  - `[-+]?` - an optional `-` or `+`
  - `\d` - a digit
  - `[\d,.]*` - 0 or more digits, `,` or `.`

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/zTH2M1):

```
import re
st='''["FL gr_20 T3\'><strong>+1,921.15</strong>"]' st='["FL gr_20 T3\'><strong>-921.15</strong>"]' st='["FL gr_20 T3\'><strong>21.15</strong>"]' st='["FL gr_20 T3\'><strong>1,11,921.15</strong>"]' st='["FL gr_20 T3\'><strong>1,921</strong>"]' st='["FL gr_20 T3\'><strong>112921</strong>"]' st='["FL gr_20 T3\'><strong>1.15</strong>"]' st='["FL gr_20 T3\'><strong>1</strong>"]'''
print(re.findall(r'>([-+]?\d[\d,.]*)<', st))
# => ['+1,921.15', '-921.15', '21.15', '1,11,921.15', '1,921', '112921', '1.15', '1']
```

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot for providing the regex r'>([-+]?\d[\d,.]*)<', and the explaination, now the regex is working perfectly for +ve/-ve and any length of values.

Answer (score 0):

Your regexp doesnt take into account when a number has ',' and '.'
You could use the below regexp to match all cases:

```
re.findall(r'[-+]?\d+(?:,\d+)?(?:\.\d+)?'
```

Answer (score 0):

Just substitute out the commas and cast to a float:

```
In [1]: l = ['1,921.15', '921.15', '921', '1,921']
   ...:

In [2]: l
Out[2]: ['1,921.15', '921.15', '921', '1,921']

In [3]: [float(x.replace(',','')) for x in l]
Out[3]: [1921.15, 921.15, 921.0, 1921.0]
```

If you really want to get rid of `.0`s, use `is_integer()` to cast only whole numbers:

```
In [4]: [int(f) if f.is_integer() else f for f in [float(x.replace(',','')) for x in l]]
Out[4]: [1921.15, 921.15, 921, 1921]
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your trying to capture all of any valid number format so this would work:

```
[+-]?\d+(?:,\d{3})*(\.\d+)*
```

https://regex101.com/r/5bygVO/1